# What is to be considered a "body" in physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology

Well, the question says it all; is there a definition of [body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_body) in physics? What is to be considered a physical object and what it cannot?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general definition of a body for physics, as in everyday speech  where one has to qualify further either by context or content.

A body of water, means a bulk  ensemble of water molecules and further analysis depends on the context.

Two colliding bodies could be billiard balls or asteroids. It is a blanket term that needs further attributes if it is to be used in a problem that needs a mathematical solution in physics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about *rigid* bodies like billiard balls or asteroids one has a definition of a body:

> In physics, a rigid body is an idealization of a solid body in which deformation is neglected. In other words, the distance between any two given points of a rigid body remains constant in time regardless of external forces exerted on it.([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body))

However this seem a little bit fishy since it also uses the word “body” in its definition. However one can also define a body in Classical Mechanics as a collection of atoms (or just one atom for that matter) having a well-defined energy, velocity, mass and momentum. Things get a little complicated when you are dealing with QM.

To answer your second question: You can think of anything as physical object so long as you obey the above-mentioned rules. E.g. a body with infinite mass is not a physical object, it is just an *idealisation* of a very heavy physical object.